# default function parameter based on input type

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a case where i want the default function parameter to change when the input type has specified certain traits, for example a pmr object has an allocator trait, and `get_allocator` function, so how do i do that ? I would appreciate a c++20 solution that doesn't involve SFINAE unless otherwise impossible maybe using if constexpr or concepts, i don't want to write two functions unless otherwise impossible.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void new_deleter(T* ptr)
{
    delete ptr;
}

template <typename T>
void pmr_deleter(T* ptr)
{
    ptr->get_allocator().delete_object(ptr);
}

template<typename T>
using deleter_t = void (*)(T*);

// use pmr_deleter by default when possible
template<typename T>
void delete_object(T* ptr, deleter_t<T> deleter = &new_deleter<T>)
{
    deleter(ptr);
}
```

Edit: thanks to the answer i figured out the following pattern, which could easily be adapted to concepts and if contexpr.

```
template<typename T>
deleter_t get_default_deleter() {return &new_deleter<T>;}

template<typename T>
deleter_t get_default_deleter() 
requires requires (T* ptr) {ptr->get_allocator();}
{
 return &pmr_deleter<T>;
}

template<typename T>
void delete_object(T* ptr, deleter_t<T> deleter = get_default_deleter<T>())
{
    deleter(ptr);
}
```

Comment: _i don't want to write two functions unless otherwise impossible_ -- why this arbitrary requirement? I mean you've already written three functions.

Comment: @chrysante i am trying to avoid code duplication, having many functions that differ only in the default parameter is ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload the functions and use the fact that more constrained functions will be selected over less constrained functions.

```
// Default delete
template<typename T>
void delete_object(T* ptr) {
    delete ptr;
}

// This will be selected if ptr->get_allocator().delete_object(ptr) is well formed
template<typename T>
void delete_object(T* ptr) 
    requires requires { ptr->get_allocator().delete_object(ptr); } 
{
    ptr->get_allocator().delete_object(ptr);
}

// Or explicitly specify the deleter if necessary
template<typename T>
using deleter_t = void (*)(T*);

template<typename T>
void delete_object(T* ptr, deleter_t<T> deleter) {
    deleter(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use two overloads, you can simply use `if constexpr` in the function body

```
template<typename T>
void delete_object(T* ptr) {
  if constexpr (requires { ptr->get_allocator().delete_object(ptr); })
    ptr->get_allocator().delete_object(ptr); // pmr deleter
  else
    delete ptr; // new deleter
}
```